# Are there any benchmarks comparing Java 8 Streams to Guava Iterables?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, guava

I'm happy enough with Guava on Java 8 - are there any performance benefits or pitfalls in migrating to Streams for sequential code?

Comment: Well, uhm, do you have use cases? If yes you could try and microbenchmark the stuff

Comment: The JIT has been significantly optimised for Streams in Java 8.  Even if you don't change your code you should use the Java 8 JVM.  This may make more difference with less effort.

Comment: I could um, benchmark my use cases, but I'd rather see some research to help decide whether to default to Streams or Iterables for my run of the mill code.

Comment: Note that the Guava team contributed to the design of Java 8 streams and we generally consider them superior to our stuff.  Hooray for the march of progress!

Answer (score 3):

I've started [a project on GitHub](https://github.com/dmcg/iterables-v-streams) to play with this.

Initial results are surprisingly positive for Streams - for an identity map over strings, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode) on 2014 MacBookAir 1.7Ghz i7, code version https://github.com/dmcg/iterables-v-streams#ea8498ee0627fc59834001a837fa92fba4bcf47ebcf47e

```
Experiment selection: 
  Benchmark Methods:   [guava, iterate, streams]
  Instruments:   [allocation, runtime]
  User parameters:   {}
  Virtual machines:  [default]
  Selection type:    Full cartesian product

This selection yields 6 experiments.
Trial Report (1 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=iterate, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    bytes(B): min=4072.00, 1st qu.=4072.00, median=4072.00, mean=4072.00, 3rd qu.=4072.00, max=4072.00
    objects: min=3.00, 1st qu.=3.00, median=3.00, mean=3.00, 3rd qu.=3.00, max=3.00
Trial Report (2 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=guava, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    bytes(B): min=15104.00, 1st qu.=15104.00, median=15104.00, mean=15104.00, 3rd qu.=15104.00, max=15104.00
    objects: min=17.00, 1st qu.=17.00, median=17.00, mean=17.00, 3rd qu.=17.00, max=17.00
Trial Report (3 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=streams, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    bytes(B): min=15272.00, 1st qu.=15272.00, median=15272.00, mean=15527.64, 3rd qu.=15432.00, max=17252.80
    objects: min=20.00, 1st qu.=20.00, median=20.00, mean=25.00, 3rd qu.=26.00, max=53.00
Trial Report (4 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=runtime, benchmarkMethod=guava, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    runtime(ns): min=13365.32, 1st qu.=13660.61, median=13802.51, mean=13961.91, 3rd qu.=14445.46, max=14715.34
Trial Report (5 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=runtime, benchmarkMethod=iterate, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    runtime(ns): min=9952.47, 1st qu.=10892.64, median=11372.35, mean=11243.07, 3rd qu.=11785.48, max=12024.76
Trial Report (6 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=runtime, benchmarkMethod=streams, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    runtime(ns): min=10527.26, 1st qu.=11051.70, median=11747.29, mean=11631.15, 3rd qu.=12205.97, max=12581.39
Collected 81 measurements from:
  2 instrument(s)
  2 virtual machine(s)
  3 benchmark(s)

Execution complete: 1.188 min.
Results have been uploaded. View them at: https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/d2c7f83b-2cfa-4217-ab0b-e8d506eaa85c
```

I'm still getting my head around Google calipers, but it seems to suggest that Streams are faster than Guava, and not much slower than a straight for loop.

Comment: Caliper suffers from correctness issues, e.g. due to loop unrolling. [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh) is the preferred benchmarking tool.

Comment: Dammit I thought it was safe to go with Google. Nevertheless I'm supposing that loop unrolling won't make much difference here.

Comment: That was one of many flaws, including dead code elimination (since you don't return a value). Caliper was based on advise from Bloch's [Performance Anxiety](https://www.parleys.com/play/2103), Click's [Art of Benchmarking](http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2009/session/2009_J1_Benchmark.pdf), and feedback from the Android team. No one involved was a VM engineer, it mimics a basic harness, and is useless for complex scenarios (like threading). It was a better default for blog posts and sanity checking for regressions, but unusable for serious work (e.g. Guava's are mostly meaningless).

Comment: @BenManes How about the evidence please? For example a Guava benchmark redone in JMH with significantly different results, and how you know which one is the "correct" one?

Comment: I'll try to get to this over the weekend, first by recreating some of the issues I ran into back in `0.5-rc1` and see if they're still applicable. In particular trying to analyze the effects of memory barriers was very frustrating in Caliper, but appeared to match McKenney's descriptions in JMH.

Comment: We would really appreciate the hard data; no one's been able to supply it yet. The other thing is that Caliper's actual measuring strategy is pluggable and the one that's currently the default is ... well, it's just currently the default. It could have been swapped, but instead an entirely separate framework was made.

Comment: @BenManes What did you find out over that weekend? ;)

Comment: @Xaerxess That its much harder to design a fair single-threaded benchmark to find problems then it is to diagnose a broken one. I benchmarked & vs &&, which resulted in different winners. I used C++ as a tie breaker, which agreed with JMH.